# php-fpm nginx magento2 user can't view another page if php still processing

Tags: php, nginx, magento2

Is this a feature of php, nginx, or magento2 and how do I disable it?  I've verified that if a user has a php process running (such as something that takes a long time like a product search) loading other pages is queued up for them and doesn't process until their prior page request finishes.

Comment: its due to *session locking* its pretty common

Comment: Thanks for your info - if you want some points you can put an answer i'll mark it complete.